# How to wait for URL to contain text using Playwright

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I'm clicking on an element on my page and being redirected to another page.

How to test using `Playwright` and `Expect` that the url was updated?

```
def is_url_contains(self, text_in_url):
    try:
        expect(self.page).to_have_url(text_in_url, timeout=10 * 1000)
        return True
    except AssertionError:
        return False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-pageassertions#page-assertions-to-have-url)

```
import re
    
    import pytest
    import unittest
    
    from playwright.sync_api import Page, expect
    
    
    class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
        @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
        def setup(self, page: Page):
            self.page = page
    
        def test_foobar(self):
            self.page.goto("https://www.wikipedia.org/")
    
            # Create a locator
            en_wikipedia = self.page.get_by_title("English — Wikipedia — The Free Encyclopedia")
    
            # Click link to start navigation
            en_wikipedia.click()
    
            # Expects the URL to contain Main_Page.
            expect(self.page).to_have_url(re.compile(".*/Main_Page"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just simply:

```
self.page.wait_for_url("**/shouldcontainthis/**")
```

Comment: Huge time saviour! For some reason regex like `r'some_str'` is not working in `page.wait_for_url()`.